# Magnetic effect to draw coins

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, unity3d-2dtools

I have a space ship and some coins in my game. When I move my space ship towards the coins I want to have a magnetic effect so that the spaceship draws all the coins in. The code below does not work in my case. I have a circlecollider2d attached to a child of all my coins. The idea is when any coin comes nearer and nearer towards my spaceship the spaceship draws all of the coins in. But it's not working (no magnetic effect).

This code is attached to the coin.

```
public GameObject attractedTo;
public float radius;
public float force;

private bool inside;
private Transform magnet;

private Rigidbody2D rb;


void Start() {
    rb = attractedTo.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    magnet = GameObject.Find("Magnet").GetComponent<Transform>();

    inside = false;
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    if(inside) {
        Vector3 magnetField = attractedTo.transform.position - magnet.position;
        magnetField.z = 0;
        float index = (radius - magnetField.magnitude) / radius;
        rb.AddForce(force * magnetField * index, ForceMode2D.Force);
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "PlayerShipTag") {
        inside = true;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D (Collider2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "PlayerShipTag") {
        inside = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, do you mean that *nothing* is happening or something is happening but not what you want.

Comment: The magnetic effect is not appearing. They fall down because of the Rigidbody2D-component (gravity).

Comment: Can you confirm, ie with a breakpoint, that `inside` is getting set correctly?

Comment: Yes. inside works. I have two colliders attached to a coin. A boxCollider2D and a CircleCollider2D. Both get messed up when they try to trigger the BoxCollider2D of the spaceship.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say the colliders are getting messed up. What goes wrong with them?

Comment: I am not able to distinguish between them (i.e. I want to trigger the CircleCollider2d of the coin with the BoxCollider2D of the spaceship). The problem is that the BoxCollider2D AND the CircleCollider2D of the coin trigger the BoxCollider2D of the spaceship. I want that the CircleCollider2D triggers only when they meet the spaceship.

Comment: Do you need the colliders at all?  You can just have the coins ignore the ship when the distance between is greater than radius.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is attached to each coin, and you want the your force to be applied to each coin.  This line in `Start`:

```
rb = attractedTo.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

I'm assuming that `attractedTo` is the spaceship? Well later on, in `FixedUpdate`, you are applying a force to rb.

```
rb.AddForce(force * magnetField * index, ForceMode2D.Force);
```

So if I understand your code correctly, you are applying a force to the **spaceship**, not the coins.

You need to add a RigidBody2D to each coin and apply the force (calculated properly) to the coin's RigidBody2d.

**Edit**: in regard to your comment about coins falling because of gravity, you can always turn gravity off for the coin rigidbody.

**Edit**: One additional note is that you are using the vector from magnet to spaceship as the direction of your force.  But you aren't normalizing it to a unit vector and so your force vary based on distance (which is good except you are already accounting for that with index).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out ASAP.:)

Comment: Ok. I changed it. But when I come closer to the coins they fly weird across the screen.

Comment: I added an edit with an issue with the direction of you magnetField.  Otherwise if you are finding the coins moving too quickly or whatever, try starting with a very low force value and gradually tweak until you get the right response.